# What are those Cupertino fields in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

I see these fields everywhere, these tiles. How are they called in flutter? Where can I find or how can I build them?
(I'm talking about these 4 tiles).[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below on various `Cupertino Widgets` and how to use them:

[Cupertino Widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino)

I hope this answers your question

Comment: There aren't those fields. Like, those list tiles. There is that top app bar, the buttons, but not those list tiles. Instagram uses those tiles, Tinder, I think even facebook. Aren't those iOS styled widgets?

Comment: For the listtiles, you can use the ```ListTile``` widget followed by a ```Divider``` widget. @AlexandruStroescu

Comment: So there is no cupertino field or list tile or what those apps are using in flutter? I should build them myself?

Comment: There are no cupertino listtile. You can customize the llisttile to look like cupertino @AlexandruStroescu